# problem loading stylesheets to wp_head dynamically

Tags: functions, variables, actions, css

I'm trying to create a wrapper shortcut function to register and load stylesheets in the header. currently, the function loads this css file src:

```
http://my.test/wp-content/theme/css/.css
```

I, obviously want it to pass the parameter given. The problem is, the new function definition within the new function definition doesn't seem to be taking the parameter even though my #4th argument for add_action was 1 (parameter passable to function).

What am I doing wrong?? Please help :)

```
<?php //Registering stylesheets

load_stylesheet_like_a_boss('my-style.css');

function load_stylesheet_like_a_boss($filename){
    echo 'parent:'.$filename; //should return 'parent: my-style.css'
        add_action('wp_head', 'stylesheet_registration', 5, 1); 

        function stylesheet_registration($filename){
        echo ' / child:'.$filename.'<br>'; //should return ' / child: my-style.css'
        $name = str_replace('.css','', $filename);

        wp_register_style($name, get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/css/'.$name.'.css');
        wp_enqueue_style($name, 10);
    }
} ?>
```

Comment: Why are you trying to create a wrapper for a hook callback? IOW, where/how do you intend to call `load_stylesheet_like_a_boss()`, and why do you need to use the wrapper, instead of simply creating a hook callback to enqueue your stylesheet?

Answer (score 1):

While your code is a bit messy, I think the one thing that is breaking it is the `wp_enqueue_style` you've got there. The second parameter "10" just shouldn't be there.

Comment: thanks man, made no difference. still didn't work. so I got around it another way, thanks :)

Comment: Harley, you should post your answer here and accept it so that others who are in the same situation can learn from it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a few problems:

1. The code is unnecessarily complex
2. You're passing the wrong arguments to `wp_enqueue_style()`. (You appear to be passing a *priority*, which this function does not accept.)
3. You're *echoing* inside of a callback that isn't intended to *output* anything
4. Conceptually, the idea of a wrapper for an enqueue action callback just doesn't seem to make sense.

Try something like this, instead:

```
<?php
function load_stylesheet_like_a_boss( $filename ) {

    if ( false == $filename ) {
        return;
    } else {

        function enqueue_stylesheet_like_a_boss( $filename ) {
            // Stylesheet handle
            // Returns all but the ".css" from $filename
            $handle = substr( $filename, 0, -4 );
            // Stylesheet path
            $path = get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/' . $filename;
            // Enqueue
            wp_enqueue_style( $handle, $path );
        }
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_stylesheet_like_a_boss' );

    }   
}
?>
```

Note: the `load_stylesheet_like_a_boss()` function **must** be called *prior to the `wp_head` action firing*. That means that it probably shouldn't be called in the template at all, but rather in `functions.php`, and hooked in somewhere - which causes me to wonder why you need such a wrapper at all?